# Unable to build maven project from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Getting error while build the project from jenkin

Below is the error

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project : Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: basedir /root/.jenkins/workspace/projectname does not exist ->

Answer (score 2):

Is because of job setup issue. Please create a folder named your_job_name at `/root/.jenkins/workspace/`

OR also you can Delete Pipeline/Job and recreate new job and try to build again.